# Regarding character decoding and mime decoding

Tags: mime-types, utf8-decode

I have developed a program in java which fetches subject, sender, from and datetime of email information from an email account. I have done that using html parser and httpclient. I have two problems.

1. When I parse a subject string of the email I get some wiered character sometimes. for e.g. if subject is "Hi Mr. müller", I receive subject string as "Hi Mr. mÃ¼ller". As you can see it's not giving ü character properly. Any idea which encoding is this ? Is it UTF-8 ? How do I decode it to get the original string ?
2. I have also received email information like subject, sender, receiver, datetime etc. from yahoo account with pop3. In that I have noticed when the sender email id contains ü or ue (for e.g. reva.müller@gmx.de), it encodes it like ('=?iso-8859-1?Q?=22Reva_M=FCller=22?= '). Any idea about which encoding is this ? Is it mime encoding ? How do I decode it in java to get correct sender string ?

I would really appreciate any help.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt. It will tell you how to interpret those = signs.

See "6.7.  Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding".

Also look for a Content-Type header to clue you in on the encoding.